# Referencing Field names in Access Query

Tags: ms-access

Can I reference a field name in Access query to be used in a calculation?

I am using a cross-tab query and my headers are dates

Comment: I think we need a little more information here. What version of access is it? how is the query being executed?

Comment: Access field names should not start with a number (like a date 1-1-2015). Make sure you don't use field name like "Date". You should use something like Date1 or FirstDate.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the query as source and open a recordset, rs. 
Then rs(0) .. rs(n) will represent the fields.